# understanding LINUX_VERSION_CODE

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Im wrinting a kernel module and i found a problem testing my LKM again centos 7.

uname -a print 3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64, and i'm compiling my KM with this kernel-headers /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64/ and using LINUX_VERSION_CODE to define my code sections.

my problem is, the compilation fail because the kernel-headers include code added in more new kernel version but LINUX_VERSION_CODE returns 3.10.

for example, nf_hookfn was modify in kernel 3.13 and i have this modification already in my headers.

what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

the `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` return the Linux version *3.10* and **not** the CentOS Linux version *3.10.0-123.13.2.el7*. Theoretically, they should not apply patch with API changes ... you just discovered the reason :)

If on CentOS is possible to change stable API, they should provide something similar to `LINUX_VERSION_CODE` for CentOS.

You can define your own pre-processor variable and at compile-time assert or de-assert it according to the kernel version that you want to use (standard 3.10 or CentOS 3.10)

```
#ifdef CENTOS_PATCH /* CentOS 3.10 */
    ....
#else /* Standard 3.10 */
    ....
#endif
```

But then you have to manage two different binaries

Answer (score 1):

Centos provides some useful macro for that purpose:

```
#if RHEL_RELEASE_CODE > RHEL_RELEASE_VERSION(7,2)
//
#else
//
#endif
```

And yep, Centos custom kernel pull up some changes from recent Linux kernels.